# What equivalent "variable => array ('value')" in python?

Tags: php, python

I tried to integrate a web service (aramex tracking shipments) with my python application, they offer an example in php and I test it .. all is well, but when I turn it into python I encountered a problem to transform a array in python... (`'Shipments'    => array('XXXXXXXXXX')`), Always return:

```
'Notifications': {
    'Notification': [
        {
            'Code': 'REQ39',
            'Message': 'Shipments - Shipments List is empty'
        }
```

They offered another service "create shipment" and I integrate it into my application without any problem.

I tried this solutions:

```
Shipment = ['XXXXXXXXXX']
Shipment = ['XXXXXXXXXX',]
Shipment = ('XXXXXXXXXX',)
Shipment = {['XXXXXXXXXX']}
Shipment = {['XXXXXXXXXX',]}
```

This is the web service in PHP:

```
<?php   
$soapClient = new SoapClient('Tracking.wsdl');
echo '<pre>';
// shows the methods coming from the service 
print_r($soapClient->__getFunctions());

/*
    parameters needed for the trackShipments method , client info, Transaction, and Shipments' Numbers.
    Note: Shipments array can be more than one shipment.
*/
$params = array(
    'ClientInfo'            => array(
                                'AccountCountryCode'    => 'JO',
                                'AccountEntity'         => 'AMM',
                                'AccountNumber'         => 'NNNNN',
                                'AccountPin'            => 'NNNNNN',
                                'UserName'              => 'AAAA@AAA.com',
                                'Password'              => 'XXXXXXXXX',
                                'Version'               => 'v1.0'
                            ),

    'Transaction'           => array(
                                'Reference1'            => '001' 
                            ),
    'Shipments'             => array(
                                'XXXXXXXXXX'
                            )
);

// calling the method and printing results
try {
    $auth_call = $soapClient->TrackShipments($params);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    die('Error : ' . $fault->faultstring);
}
?>
```

And this is my python code:

```
    from zeep import Client

client =   Client('https://ws.dev.aramex.net/ShippingAPI.V2/Tracking/Service_1_0.svc?wsdl')

ClientInfo = {'UserName':'xx@xx.xx', 'Password':'xxxxx', 
'Version':'v1.0', 'AccountNumber':'xxxxxx', 'AccountPin':'xxxxxx', 
'AccountEntity':'xxx', 'AccountCountryCode':'xx'}

Transaction = {'Reference1': 'xxxx'}

Shipments = ('xxxxxxxxxxx',)

GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly = False
print(client.service.TrackShipments(ClientInfo,Transaction,Shipments,GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly))
```

And this is the error:

```
{
'Transaction': {
    'Reference1': 'xxxxx',
    'Reference2': None,
    'Reference3': None,
    'Reference4': None,
    'Reference5': None
},
'Notifications': {
    'Notification': [
        {
            'Code': 'REQ39',
            'Message': 'Shipments - Shipments List is empty'
        }
    ]
},
'HasErrors': True,
'TrackingResults': None,
'NonExistingWaybills': None
```

}

any idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A PHP `array` serves as both a `dict` and a `list`, depending on whether it contains explicit keys or not (in fact, even a combination is possible, which has no analogue on Python). So the equivalent of:

```
array('Shipments' => array('XXXXXXXXXX'))
```

is:

```
{'Shipments': ['XXXXXXXXX']}
```

Comment: It makes no difference for your answer, but since you can store numeric keys in a Python `dict`, you could say that `dict` _is_ the equivalent to a mixed-use PHP array (ugh). Though of course, you can't create one without specifying the keys...

Comment: Yes, arguably, but the keyless definition has no equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work.
Normally yes; array in php serves as both dict and list, but I tried both without result.